# Calculating a real integral using complex integration

Tags: complex-analysis

$$\int^\infty_0 \frac{dx}{x^6 + 1}$$

Does someone know how to calculate this integral using complex integrals? I don't know how to deal with the $x^6$ in the denominator.

Comment: Out of curiosity as someone who's in engineering (applied math), why are you interested in solving this integral in the first place? Does it show up in some application or how is it important in pure mathematics?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Thankfully the integrand is even, so we have

$$
\int^\infty_0 \frac{dx}{x^6 + 1} = \frac{1}{2}\int^\infty_{-\infty} \frac{dx}{x^6 + 1}.
\tag{1}
$$

To find this, we will calculate the integral

$$
\int_{\Gamma_R} \frac{dz}{z^6+1},
$$

where $\Gamma_R$ is the semicircle of radius $R$ in the upper half-plane, $C_R$, together with the line segment between $z=-R$ and $z=R$ on the real axis.

[image]

(Image courtesy of [Paul Scott](http://paulscottinfo.ipage.com/index2/index2.html).)

Then

$$
\int_{\Gamma_R} \frac{dz}{z^6+1} = \int_{-R}^{R} \frac{dx}{x^6+1} + \int_{C_R} \frac{dz}{z^6+1}.
$$

We need to show that the integral over $C_R$ vanishes as $R \to \infty$.  Indeed, the triangle inequality gives

$$\begin{align}
\left| \int_{C_R} \frac{dz}{z^6+1} \right| &\leq L(C_R) \cdot \max_{C_R} \left| \frac{1}{z^6+1} \right| \\
           &\leq \frac{\pi R}{R^6 - 1},
\end{align}$$

where $L(C_R)$ is the length of $C_R$.  From this we may conclude that

$$
\lim_{R \to \infty} \int_{\Gamma_R} \frac{dz}{z^6+1} = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{dx}{x^6+1}.
\tag{2}
$$

The integral on the left is evaluated by the residue theorem.  For $R > 1$ we have

$$
\int_{\Gamma_R} \frac{dz}{z^6+1} = 2\pi i \sum_{k=0}^{2} \operatorname{Res}\left(\frac{1}{z^6+1},\zeta^k \omega\right),
$$

where $\zeta$ is the primitive sixth root of unity and $\omega = e^{i\pi/6}$.  Note that this is because $\omega$, $\zeta\omega$, and $\zeta^2 \omega$ are the only poles of the integrand inside $\Gamma_R$.  [The sum of the residues can be calculated directly](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/122405/5531), and we find that

$$
\int_{\Gamma_R} \frac{dz}{z^6+1} = 2\pi i \sum_{k=0}^{2} \operatorname{Res}\left(\frac{1}{z^6+1},\zeta^k \omega\right) = \frac{\pi}{3 \sin(\pi/6)} = \frac{2\pi}{3}.
$$

Thus, from $(1)$ and $(2)$ we conclude that

$$
\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{dx}{x^6+1} = \frac{\pi}{3}.
$$

In general,

$$
\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{dx}{x^{2n}+1} = \frac{\pi}{2 n \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2n}\right)}
$$

for $n \geq 1$.

Comment: Beautiful solution.  (I started to write up a solution, but it wasn't this elegant.)

Comment: Very nice mate, cheers. Havent done residues yet...I was thinking I would have to get 6th roots of -1 to find all the singularites...and then use CIF multiple times to get the integral. Residues let you skip all that stuff yes?

Comment: @Jim_CS, yes, precisely.  The residue theorem can essentially be seen as an application of Cauchy's integral formula (in addition to many other interesting interpretations).

Comment: To achieve the following development in $(1)$, did you use the Cauchy Integral Formula ?

$(1)$

$$ \int_{\Gamma_R} \frac{dz}{z^6+1} = \int_{-R}^{R} \frac{dx}{x^6+1} + \int_{C_R} \frac{dz}{z^6+1}$$

Comment: @Zophikel No, that's simply an application of the integration rule $$\int_a^c = \int_a^b + \int_b^c.$$ For example, $$\int_1^3 = \int_1^2 + \int_2^3.$$ You can prove that this implies the breakdown in the formula you gave by the definition of contour integration (by parameterizing the contour).

Comment: Ahh okay now I understand

Comment: When applying the Estimation theorem, did you by any chance mean to write $\frac{\pi R}{R^6 + 1}$?

Comment: @Threnody No. When $R > 1$ and $|z| = R$, the reverse triangle inequality gives $|z^6 + 1| \geq |z^6| - |1| = R^6 - 1 > 0$, so that $|1/(z^6 + 1)| \leq 1/(R^6 - 1)$.

Answer (score 4):

$$\int_0^\infty\frac{dx}{x^6+1}=\frac{1}{2}\lim_{R\to\infty}I_R$$ where $$I_R:=\int_{-R}^{R}\frac{dx}{x^6+1}.$$
Let us integrate $f(z):=\frac{1}{1+z6}$ along the closed oriented curve constituted by the upper semicircumpherence $C_R$ with center $0$ and radius $R>1$ and the interval $[-R,R]$.

Applying the residue theorem we get $$I_R+\int_{C_R}f(z)dz=2\pi i\sum_{k=1}^3\textrm{Res}(f;\textrm{exp}(\frac{1+2k}{6}i\pi)).\qquad(*)$$

Remarking $\lim_{R\to\infty}\int_{C_R}f(z)dz=0,$ from $(*)$ you get your integral.

Answer (score 0):

You can split the denominator by taking $x^6$ as $(x^2)^3$,
and then use $a^3+b^3=(a+b)(a^2-ab+b^2)$. After using this formula, 
you will get $x^6+1=(x^2+1)(x^4-x^2+1)$. Then you can use partial fraction decomposition.

If you still don't get it, then [here](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=jSRKQ19d-nc) is another better method in this little video.

Comment: Welcome on the MathSE! Note, we have Latex support here. Type if `$x^2$` and you will get $x^2$.