# $\int^\infty_0 \frac{dx}{x^n + 1}$, n odd

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

Well, I saw this integral :

$$\int^\infty_0 \frac{dx}{x^n + 1}$$

on some questions (like this one : [Calculating a real integral using complex integration](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/135917/calculating-a-real-integral-using-complex-integration) )

But it has always been for $n$ even.
Is there something wrong with $n$ odd ? Is not, how do you compute this ? by the same argument ?

thank you and sorry if this is easy. I can't figure out how to do it since it's neither odd nor even.

Comment: Integrate over a sector of a circle centred at the origin, with one side on the $x$-axis, and the other side making an angle of $2\pi/n$ with it.

Comment: Hi! You can also just set $n=0$ here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/110457/515527 and obtain what you desire.

Comment: Thank you I ll check that. I think it solves my problem.